# how to extract the URL

Tags: python, html, selenium

I tried to extract the data from this website - https://hk.centanet.com/findproperty/list/transaction?q=xXHFRIuxWUSNboTJYGkUIg.  I have the following problem:-

1. when I click the line item, the website pointed to other URL (https://hk.centanet.com/findproperty/transaction-detail/-%E5%BE%A1%E7%9A%87%E5%BA%AD_AJP202209S0604).  After press "back forword" arrow, the website always go to the firt page.
2. I can't find the href of the line item.

I use python and selenium
do anyone have idea to solve my problems? Thanks in advance.

========
The below program is upto now, I can think about to fix this issue.....hahahaha

```
row_num=1
web_click = "//*[@class='cv-structured-list-item cv-structured-list-item--standard bx--structured-list-row'][{}]/div[1]".format(row_num)
click_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath(web_click)
click_date.click()
time.sleep(3)

driver.back()
time.sleep(3) 
                
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='el-pagination el-pagination--small']/ul/li[2]")
link.click() # click on "Next Page" link
time.sleep(3) 

row_num=2
web_click = "//*[@class='cv-structured-list-item cv-structured-list-item--standard bx--structured-list-row'][{}]/div[1]".format(row_num)
click_date = driver.find_element_by_xpath(web_click)
click_date.click()
time.sleep(3)

driver.back()
time.sleep(3) 

link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='el-pagination el-pagination--small']/ul/li[2]")
link.click() # click on "Next Page" link
time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get each page with driver.get(url).I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your information but it's not what I want.  It returns the first page for me.